# New Spring 21 sandbox SOQL query fails on encrypted Account Name

Tags: soql, shield-encryption

Spun up a new Spring 21 sandbox from our Shield Platform-encrypted PROD org.  PROD has `Account.Name` deterministic, case-insensitive encryption.

- Created a new Account with name = `foo`
- Went to Developer Console and entered

  ```
   SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Name = 'foo'
  ```
- RESULT: **0 records found!?!**

*N.B. Issue discovered when running unit tests*

Same query works fine on existing orgs, PROD included, that were upgraded to Spring 21 as part of the SFDC release.

What is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would surmise this is a bug -- the workaround is to generate new Tenant Secrets in the sandbox

```
Setup | Platform Encryption | Key Management
```

[image]

I got the workaround idea from: [How does Shield Platform Encryption Work in Sandboxes](https://dreamevent.secure.force.com/articleView?id=sf.security_pe_sandboxes.htm&type=5)

> As a best practice, rotate tenant secrets on sandboxes after a refresh. Rotation ensures that production and sandbox use different tenant secrets. Destroying tenant secrets on a sandbox renders encrypted data unusable in cases of partial or full copies.